# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in BookingsController#create Couldn't find Appointment without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

app/controllers/bookings_controller.rb:45:in `create'

I have an Appointments object and a Bookings object. Bookings belongs to Appointments and Appointments has_many bookings.

I want to create a bookings object that has :appointment_id

Here is my code:

```
<% @appointments.each do |appointment| %>
    <%= link_to "new Booking", new_appointment_booking_path(appointment)%>
<%end%>
```

Bookings Controller:

```
def new
    @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:appointment_id])
    @booking = @appointment.bookings.new 
    ...

 def create
I was missing [:booking] in line 45. 
 Line 45:   @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:booking][:appointment_id])
     @booking = @appointment.bookings.new(params[:booking])
```

routes

```
resources :appointments do
    resources :bookings
end
```

When I submit my Bookings_form the correct appointment_id is passed through 
but I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in BookingsController#create
Couldn't find Appointment without an ID
```

Booking _form

```
<%= simple_form_for(@booking) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :appointment_date %>
    <%= f.input :start_time %>
    <%= f.input :end_time %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :phone_number %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :appointment_id%>  

 <div class="form-actions">
     <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
```

Comment: How does your form look like?

Comment: could you tell which line is line 45 in the controller?

Comment: Line 45 is in create action:  @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:appointment_id])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing the Appointment id back to the `create` method.

The `create` method knows nothing except the info passed in through the params hash from the form inputs. Seeing as you haven't added a field to the form for `appointment_id`, it's not getting passed to the controller and isn't available in the `create` method.

To get around this, add a new hidden input to your form like this:

```
<%= f.input :appointment_id, :type => :hidden %>
```

Now you're explicitly passing the id through the form post, so it'll be available in your controller.

Comment: thanks for the reply David. I tried that and the appointment_id is being passed but it still gives me the same error. Any idea what else it could be?

Comment: The `appointment_id` param will be inside your `booking`, have you tried accessing it like this: `params[:booking][:appointment_id]`?